# How Java 8 has concrete methods in Collection Interface?

Tags: java, collections, interface, java-8

[image]I was referring to the Collection Interface of Java 8, where I saw that Collection method has concrete method **public boolean removeIf(Predicate paramPredicate)** , but as per the definition of Interface we can only have static and default method with body and rest can be abstract.
I tried creating the concrete method in an Interface and received compile time error **Abstract methods do not specify a body** with 3 quick fixes from eclipse:

1. Change method to default
2. Change method to static
3. Remove method body

Can anyone explain how Collection interface has concrete implementation of methods **removeIf** , **spliterator** , **stream** , **parallelStream** ?

Comment: It's a `default` method : `default boolean removeIf(Predicate<? super E> filter)`

Comment: Default Methods in interfaces is a new feature of Java 8...

Comment: @Nirekin that "new" feature will turn 5 years very soon

Comment: @Eugene ... and Java 8 itself is end of public updates in Jan '19. ;)

Comment: My decompiler is showing it as public, got it verified from official site https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html it is default method. :p